# Encrypt string using RSA algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography

Encrypt the $3-$digit string $231$ using the key $(1219,7)$ and the RSA encryption algorithm. What is the new string of numbers?

I have found that $$M' \equiv 231^7 \pmod {1219} \equiv 875 \pmod {1219}$$ Is that all this is asking?

Comment: Assuming the key, $(n, e)$, is how it is written, it looks good.

Comment: Thats all. Unlike DES and AES which require long sequence of operations, of various kinds to be executed in particular order RSA is conceptually simple.